# How to using Windows store app (same as winRT/metro) library in WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, wifi-direct

I want to using Windows Runtime Libary(winRT) in WPF Application. (win8.1)

my WPF application needs to WiFiDirect.

but WiFiDirect library is only in WinRT!
(namespace Windwos.Networking.Proximity)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.networking.proximity.aspx

so i hope to using winRT in wpf app.

How to using winRT library in WPF?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How to call WinRT APIs in Windows 8 from C# Desktop Applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are going other way.

In theory you can not use a dll created for higher version or a different framework by referencing.

Perhaps you can link them via creating a communication channel between these two.

So create an executable wrapper for your WinRT library (service) in the same framework and do connect with your WPF app by using one of them or perhaps other communication approach

so possible options but not limited to are

- [Messaging with MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx)
- [Sockets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using)
- [Interprocess Communication with Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085)

and perhaps more